# Match string until x but not succeeded by y

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in which I'm trying to capture everything up to the first "~" which is *not* succeeded by a "=".

```
input.error[data-groups~=5]~label.light[data-groups~=5]
│                          │
└  Desired capture region  ┘
```

If I understand correctly, for this I should be using negative look ahead

Here is my attempt so far:

```
(^[^~]+(?!=))
```

The idea being that `[^~]+` will consume everything until a "~" is encountered provided it is not succeeded by a "=" using the directive `(?!=)`

But this expression only captures everything up to the first "~"

Sorry If this seems a poor attempt, regular expressions are not really my forte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there: You forgot to actually match the `~`!

```
(^[^~]*~(?!=))
```

Nope, not quite: This looks for a ~ not followed by `=`, but there must not be *any* tildes earlied in the line. So it will still fail. You can expand your regexp, but in my opinion it would be simpler to match until the first qualifying `~` by using "non-greedy" wildcards:

```
(^.*?~(?!=))
```

This will stop at the first match, but will match anything until that point.

Comment: Ok, thats perfect. I wander, could you explain briefly why it uses "*" instead of "+" ?

Comment: @andrew I'm not sure why you expected `+`, but the "non-greedy" operator `*?` is similar to `*` except that it stops as soon as possible (plain `*` matches as much as possible). If you write `.+?` instead, you'll need to match at least one character before the `~`.

Comment: The fact that the OP used `+` indicates to me that he doesn't want zero-length matches; I don't see any justification for changing it to `*`.  I know it doesn't matter in this case (it still has to match from the start of the string to the first `~`), but the choice of quantifiers can have a huge effect on performance and correctness.  Overriding the author's choice in this matter is not something to be done lightly.

Comment: My perception is that this was an accident: I see no indication, in the question or in the regexp, that he _intended_ to exclude line-initial tildes. Anyway I show how to solve the general problem (always a good approach imho), and I hope my answer and previous comment give all readers enough information to modify this if their needs are different.

Answer (score 2):

Try `.*?~` instead of `[^~]+`:

```
^(.*?~)(?!=)
```